# Filter does not filter the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I asked this question before, and I still didn't manage to fix it. Can someone please help.

I have a filter function:

```
$scope.filterByTimestamp = function(filter){
     console.log("blah");
    return $scope.timestamp = new Date($scope.startDate).getTime();
 }
```

"blah" logs in the console twice, and it logs 11374 times. I filter my Html view like this:

```
 <label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">Date</span>
  <input type="date" ng-model="startDate" >
</label>
     </div>
<div ng-model="timestamphope">{{timestamp}} </div>          
   <div ng-repeat="x in result ">
   <div ng-repeat="y in x.rates  | filterByTimestamp ">
   {{y[0]}} 
   </div>
</div>
```

The view does not change. I want to show only the result that is equal to the function $scope.timestamp = new Date($scope.startDate).getTime();

Comment: change `ng-repeat="y in x.rates  | filterByTimestamp "` to `ng-repeat="y in x.rates  | filter:{y.time == Timestamp}"`

Comment: I get a syntax error on .Time since time is not defined in my server. What I want to filter trough are arrays that look like this [978307200000,1.975]. I tried filter:{y[0] == Timestamp} but I still got the same error.

Comment: I mean add your index which you want to compare with `Timestamp ` from your response.

Comment: Is there a way to check what that index is? Sorry for the basic questions, but I'm new to programming.

Comment: can you post json response ?

Comment: I'm looping trough a lot of arrays that look like this "rates":[[978307200000,1.975],[978393600000,1.975]... The index of y should be 0, right?